# Confusion concerning NSClassFromString / Checking for Gesture Recognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios-3.x

I'm trying to use NSClassFromString to prevent a block of code from running on pre iOS 3.2 devices. The code block in question is as follows:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UITapGestureRecognizer"))
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                          action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)] autorelease];
    [tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

I'm doing this because Apple's documentation states that UITapGestureRecognizer is incompatable with pre 3.2 installations. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I originally thought that using NSClassFromString would return nil when I ran it on this device, but it does not. The statement is true and the code executes. (An interesting note, the code *sort of* works on a pre 3.2 installation.)

Anyway, I'd like to know why NSClassFromString is NOT returning nil, and is there anything I can do otherwise to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW40)

> ### Usage Special Considerations
>
> To determine whether a class is available
> at runtime in a given iOS release, you typically check whether the
> class is nil. Unfortunately, this test is not cleanly accurate for
> UIGestureRecognizer. Although this class was publicly available
> starting with iOS 3.2, it was in development a short period prior to
> that. Although the class exists in an earlier release, use of it and
> other gesture-recognizer classes are not supported in that earlier
> release. You should not attempt to use instances of those classes.
>
> To determine at runtime whether you can use gesture recognizers in
> your application, test whether the class exists and, if it does,
> allocate an instance and see check if it responds to the selector
> locationInView:. This method was not added to the class until iOS 3.2.
> The code might look like the following:
>
> ```
> UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)];
>  
> if (![gestureRecognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(locationInView:)]) {
>     [gestureRecognizer release];
>     gestureRecognizer = nil;
> }
> // do something else if gestureRecognizer is nil
> ```

Comment: Yes, I think Apple also mentions this in one of the WWDC videos as a special case to look out for. Other people have hit this exact same issue before: http://www.nanoant.com/apple/wanna-be-3-x-compatible-not-so-simple

Answer (score 2):

What is probably happening is that UITapGestureRecognizer exists but is just not public in 3.1.3. I've had luck in the past with checking for UISplitViewController.